# What does !a mean in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I'm using SPARQL to construct a query and would like to rule out certain results.

I'm aware `FILTER NOT EXISTS` can be used to do the task. For example:

```
SELECT * {
    ?sub a ?type .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?sub a :NotExpectedType.}
}
```

But during exploration, I accidentally found I could write `!a`. That's a valid SPARQL query, but the result is different from `FILTER NOT EXISTS`. For example:

```
SELECT * {
    ?sub a ?type .
    ?sub !a :NotExpectedType .
}
```

So what does the `!a` mean? (I'm aware `a` is a shortcut for `rdf:type`, but that doesn't help me understanding yet.)

Comment: What `!` means you got in the answer below, but now the question is, do you understand **why** both queries return different results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!a` is a property path, and it means “a path of length one with a property other than `rdf:type`”.

```
SELECT ?x {
    ?x a ?type.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?x a :MyClass }
}
```

The query above will find the `?x` where no triple `?x rdf:type :MyClass` exists.

```
SELECT ?x {
    ?x a ?type.
    ?x !a :MyClass.
}
```

This query will find the `?x` where a triple `?x ?property :MyClass` exists for some `?property` other than `rdf:type`.